# MongoDB returns error "Can't canonicalize query" for sort function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

```
db.getCollection('posts').find({}, {sort: {post_id: 1}})
```

is returning

```
error: {
  "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: sort: { post_id: 1.0 }",
  "code" : 17287
}
```

I'm baffled because I've run queries almost exactly like this in the past.  I'm running it through Robomongo but it does not work from my Meteor application either.  Can anybody explain what's going on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Within Meteor the syntax is nearly as you've used:

```
YourCollection.find({}, {sort: {post_id: 1}})
```

With the MongoDB shell the format is like this:

```
db.posts.find({}).sort({post_id: 1})
```

You may still get an error at this point if you have too many results, to which you can add a limit:

```
db.posts.find({}).sort({post_id: 1}).limit(20)
```